# SymmetricDS and Postgres with UUID primary key failed (invalid input syntax for type uuid)

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

I am using Postgres 11 and SymmetricDS 3.9.14.

I have a database table with primary key of `UUID` type. It seems like SymmetricDS is not able to cast 'UUID' correctly. One of SymmetricDS replication query is failing with the below error

```
JdbcSqlTemplate - SQL caused exception: [select "id" from "dbo"."groups" where "id"=?] 
sql args: [ ] 

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: " "
```

my insert statement :-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.groups(
    id, sortorder, name, hidden, sessionid, creationtime, modificationtime, regionid)
    VALUES ('5A171D3F-F6A6-4D09-AE89-73B5793DA171', 1, 'abc', false, null,'2018-11-20 20:25:49.663', null, null);
```

my database table is :-

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.groups
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    sortorder integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    name character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hidden boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    sessionid uuid,
    creationtime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modificationtime timestamp without time zone,
    regionid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_dbo.Groups" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

EDIT:

My source database is MS SQL Server and target database is Postgres

Comment: The UUID value in the insert statement is correct and the insert statement [will work](https://rextester.com/ACPHR11346). So the data in SQL Server might not be correct or SymmetricDS does some data conversion that breaks the insert

Answer (score 0):

The value of UUID in this case is a space or tab as it could be seen from the error message

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid: " "
```

Try finding why instead of the concrete UUID value this space/tab value is passed

Comment: my source database is MS SQL server and traget is Postgres, so in SQL Server UUID format is different and Postgres understand UUID as binary data. Do you think its because of that? i dont know what configuration will fix MS SQL to postgress UUID sync. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you please help me with your input on this, how to fix this problem as both the database use different UUID format. Do i need to change something in configuration or some extra code change is required in symmtricds source code.
I am not able to find solution for this.

Comment: try checking out the code corresponding to the used version. enable remote debugging on the replication node (postgres), remote debug the java process from your dev machine and try to realise why symmetricDs is replacing the uuid sent from the central node